# Ruby proper if structure

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a web scraper. There are few variants of a page, and the program should work a little bit differently on each. I need to alternate the way it processes pages depending on what are on the page. I can do nested `if`s:

```
if str=data.css('div#imgTag').to_s
  str.delete('@') 
  #do something
elsif str=data.css('span#Title').to_s
  #do something else
elseif str=data.css('span#block').to_s
  #do something
end

return str
```

but the code above does not always work. I think there is a flaw, and I'm looking for a better way to address it. I'm looking for more elegant, construction.

Comment: there is no keyword `elseif` is it you mistype here ?

Comment: `str = ...` or `str == ...`?

Comment: `to_s` always returns a string, i.e. a *truthy* value. Therefore, your `elsif`'s are never reached.

Comment: Two things I would like to suggest. Try Gem mechanize, second use Xpath to get the exact element and use switch cases for the conditions you need the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `case when` instead of `if`, it is more practical when your several ifs are about the same variable : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Ruby_case_Statement

Otherwise, I don't really know what you can do better. You should add more details about the context of your program and what's not working.

EDIT : @Aetherus is right in the comments, you're comparing using `=` instead of `==`, which assigns a value to your variable instead of testing it, so it is always true.

EDIT AGAIN : @Stefan also have a point. If your `data.css()` returns nil, `to_s` will return an empty string which is always true. You can use `try(:to_s)` to return nil if called on a nil object (http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/Object%3Atry).

Your code becomes :

```
case str
  when data.css('div#imgTag').try(:to_s)
    str.delete('@') 
    #do something
  when data.css('span#Title').try(:to_s)
    #do something else
  when data.css('span#block').try(:to_s)
    #do something
end

return str
```